# Creating a Wrapper For HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, httpcontext

Basically I'm trying to create a SessionManager class which I can use to manage sessions in my MVC applications. For that I'm thinking the best way of doing so is by creating a wrapper class for HttpContext which would then allow me to access HttpContext.Current.Session.

To be honest, I'm not really sure about the whole thing, I just feel it's the logical way of doing so. I also want to create an ISessionManager and ISession interfaces, and then implement them according to my application's needs. For my current project, and for now, I need a InProc session management, but I might need to store session data in MSSQL Server when we decide to expand and use a web farm or a garden. That's why I'm trying to build a sort of an extensible framework right from the start.

Final note, I will be using Microsoft Unity to inject the concrete SessionManager of choice. I believe that's a good way to maintain a certain level of abstraction.

Any suggestions for achieving all that?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Don't write "maybe code" ( maybe we'll need this, maybe we'l need that ).  You area always wasting time that could be spend on features or improvements that could benefit your users now rather than later.

Comment: How will you implement `ISession` on `HttpContext.Current.Session`, which is part of the framework?

Comment: @jfar: What you said does make sense. But you might have misunderstood what I said. I want to have my code extensible, but that doesn't mean I'm going to code a Session Manager for each scenario **now**. But I'm just trying to keep everything as abstract and extensible as possible so I wouldn't have to re-create everything later on.

Comment: @Mark Avenius: I'm not going to implement those that are part of the framework, I'm trying to implement wrapper classes. But I've just read a thread which says it's bad practice to access HttpContext from the DAL or Business Layer, which does make sense actually. So I'm thinking maybe I could use a Dictionary or an Object in my service class and then feed it with HttpContext.Current.Session in my web app? What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I came up with, but I'm not sure that's the right way of doing this so your opinions are most welcome!

**ISessionManager:**

```
public interface ISessionManager  
{      
    void RegisterSession(string key, object obj);       
    void FreeSession(string key);   
}
```

**SessionManager:**

```
public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> sessionDictionary;

    public SessionManager(IDictionary<string, object> _sessionDictionary)
    {
        sessionDictionary = _sessionDictionary;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Session
    {
        get
        {
            return sessionDictionary;
        }
    }

    public void RegisterSession(string key, object obj)
    {
        sessionDictionary[key] = obj;
    }

    public void FreeSession(string key)
    {
        sessionDictionary[key] = null;
    }
}
```

Then when I want to instantiate the class (inside my web app), I would do something like that:

```
var sessionManager = new SessionManager(HttpContext.Current.Session);
sessionManager.RegisterSession["myKey"] = someObject;
```

But I would prefer to avoid using magic strings as the key. I could include a constant string property like sessionKey = "myKey" in the class, but that would mean I could only store one object in the session manager, right?

Feedback please. :)